# Paramiko Put - Send SFTP succeed but I got an error message

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am sending a file through a SFTP server which is known to be difficult (PORT: 1002_)
The file is going through but I still have the error

```
ssh_Client = pmiko.SSHClient()
ssh_Client.set_missing_host_key_policy(pmiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_Client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_Client.connect(str_host, username = str_uid, password = str_pwd, port = self.__int_portnumber)

sftp_oppen = ssh_Client.connect.open_sftp()


sftp_oppen.put(os.path.join(str_folder, str_fileName), str_fileName)
```

The error message is:
`[Errno 2] The message [/fileName.xlsx] is not extractable!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of parameter:

```
sftp_oppen.put(localpath, remotepath, confirm=False)
```